# Classe acessível em toda aplicação C#

Tags: c#, classes, instanciar-objeto, static

Gostaria que uma classe que não é estática ficasse disponível para toda a aplicação. A principio pensei em torna esta classe em estática, mas por motivos obscuros que não vem ao caso, não posso torná-la estática.

Então pesquisei algo sobre e achei algumas coisas, segue exemplo:

Considerando as classes

```
 public class TesteInstancia
{
    public decimal A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}

public static class TesteStatic
{
    public static TesteInstancia testeInstancia;
}
```

Pelo que entendi a classe `TesteStatic` vai ficar com a referencia ao objeto `TesteInstancia`.

Como passar o valor ao invés da referencia?

Existe como fazer isto de uma forma "melhor" ?

**EDIT**

Obrigado a todos pelos esclarecimentos, cheguei a uma "solução". Criando um clone da classe original ela pode ser alterada que não refletira no clone, isso resolve por enquanto meu problema, vou postar aqui.

```
public class TesteInstancia : ICloneable
{
    public decimal A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return this.MemberwiseClone();
    }
}

public static class TesteStatic 
{
    public static TesteInstancia MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Uma classe disponível ou uma instancia dessa classe?

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o que se refere quando diz **"disponível para toda a aplicação"**? Uma classe pública já está disponível.

Comment: Mas isso é uma classe estática ;) O problema é esse motivo obscuro, principalmente se não pode usar nada estático, mas a solução é usar algo estático :) A melhor forma é fazer uma classe estática logo. Você não pode armazenar um valor em algo que é uma referência. Talvez um exemplo mais concreto ajude demonstrar o que deseja.

Comment: @TotallyUncool, uma instancia da classe.

Comment: @bigown, justamente é esse motivo obscuro que atrapalha.

Comment: Fechei porque com a edição a pergunta ficou completamente sem sentido, se é isso mesmo o que havia sido perguntado originalmente e respondido não era o que queria saber de fato. Se deixar a pergunta mais clara dá para reabrir. O fato de ter uma motivo obscuro contribui também.

Comment: Singleton é a resposta pro seu problema

Comment: @TotallyUncool segundo a edição dele, não :)

Comment: @bigown é, me enganei, pelo jeito :s

Answer (score 1):

Tente uma função de inicialização:

```
public class TesteInstancia
{
    private decimal _a
    public static decimal A 
    { 
      get { Inicializar(); return _testeInstancia._a; } 
      set { Inicializar(); _testeInstancia._a = value; }  
    }

    private static TesteInstancia _testeInstancia;
    private void Inicializar()
    {
        if (_testeInstancia == null)
            _testeInstancia = new TesteInstancia();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a resposta do @maiconmm você pode fazer essa inicialização no Program.cs se for projeto Winforms ou Application console.

Você também pode ler sobre o padrão [Singleton](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton%20Singleton) para entender melhor sobre o código do maiconmm e sobre instâncias únicas de uma classe.